# Setting.bundle only for app store configuration - iOS

Tags: iphone, configuration, xcode4, ios4, xcodebuild

I'm trying to find a way to have setting.bundle for Debug Configuration but not to have it for App Store release.

I tried to write a pre build script that deletes the Setting.bundle file in case it's not Debug, however because the setting.bundle is being copied as part of the "Copy Bundle Resource" phase, it issues error.

Any way to achieve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new Target for the AppStore release. In the file inspector of the Settings.bundle deselect this new target in "Target Membership".

Answer (score 1):

Or add a build phase that runs a build script that deletes the settings bundle for your release config:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$CONFIGURATION" == "Release" ]; then
    rm -rf ${CODESIGNING_FOLDER_PATH}/Settings.bundle
fi
```